# Specific translation for "Butternut Squash"

Tags: translation, food

For a community gardening project I'm working on, I need specific translations for varieties of different strains of produce, to print in Simplified Chinese on identification stakes. In this case, I'm having trouble getting one for "Butternut Squash". Ideally it would be a name specific to that variety, so that it can be differentiated from, say, a Hubbard Squash or Zucchini Squash. Since it is a western squash, I'm getting all sorts of options, translating to "butter squash", "western squash", "winter squash", "western pecan squash"...so I need some help. What is the most common specific name for this squash? or should I use something else?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been named already - "冬南瓜".

[image]

[冬南瓜是南瓜吗?](https://www.4hw.com.cn/life/201911/458670.html#:%7E:text=%E5%8D%97%E7%93%9C%E5%A4%A7%E5%AE%B6%E9%83%BD%E7%9F%A5%E9%81%93%EF%BC%8C%E4%BD%86%E6%98%AF%E5%86%AC%E5%8D%97%E7%93%9C%E4%BC%B0%E8%AE%A1%E5%B0%B1%E8%B7%9F%E5%B0%91%E4%BA%BA%E5%90%AC%E8%BF%87%E4%BA%86%EF%BC%8C%E5%85%B6%E5%AE%9E%E5%86%AC%E5%8D%97%E7%93%9C%E4%B9%9F%E6%98%AF%E5%8D%97%E7%93%9C%E7%9A%84%E4%B8%80%E4%B8%AA%E5%93%81%E7%A7%8D%E8%80%8C%E5%B7%B2%EF%BC%8C%E4%BA%8C%E8%80%85%E7%9A%84%E5%8C%BA%E5%88%AB%E5%87%A0%E4%B9%8E%E6%98%AF%E6%B2%A1%E6%9C%89%E7%9A%84%EF%BC%8C%E4%B8%8B%E9%9D%A2%E4%BB%8B%E7%BB%8D%E5%8D%97%E7%93%9C%E7%9A%84%E8%90%A5%E5%85%BB%E4%BB%B7%E5%80%BC%E5%8F%8A%E9%A3%9F%E7%94%A8%E5%8A%9F%E6%95%88%EF%BC%9A,%E5%8D%97%E7%93%9C%E4%B8%80%E5%B9%B4%E7%94%9F%E5%8F%8C%E5%AD%90%E5%8F%B6%E8%8D%89%E6%9C%AC%E6%A4%8D%E7%89%A9%EF%BC%8C%E8%83%BD%E7%88%AC%E8%94%93%EF%BC%8C%E8%8C%8E%E7%9A%84%E6%A8%AA%E6%96%AD%E9%9D%A2%E5%91%88%E4%BA%94%E8%A7%92%E5%BD%A2%E3%80%82%20%E5%8F%B6%E5%AD%90%E5%BF%83%E8%84%8F%E5%BD%A2%E3%80%82)

Comment: This is the one that translates directly to "Winter Pumpkin" or "Winter Squash", correct?